# How to access images on server for CiviMail

Tags: civimail, images, kcfinder

I added images to the server via CiviMail (KCFinder).  But when trying to use the UI to insert an image and click "Browse Server" I receive an "Unknown Error". None of the images are displayed. I'm unable to locate the images and insert them into a new mailing. Already checked the Resource URL and Directories. See image attached. [image: Unknown Error]

CiviCRM 4.7.11 and WordPress 4.6.1

Comment: I have the same issue with WordPress 4.6.1 and 4.7.14. In my case I do not get "Unknown Error" but the waiting to load icon. It eventually times out and my only resource is to kill the page. I CAN successfully browse for images, send to the server, and insert them in my mailings. I just can't reuse them without uploading each time.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check Firewall or the settings in **WPSecurity** (plugin) if you have that installed.  I ran into this problem and it was an option in WPSecurity for "Bad Query Strings" which blocked access to thumbnails in KCFinder.

According to the plugin... **Deny Bad Query Strings**

> This feature will write rules in your .htaccess file to prevent 
>   malicious string attacks on your site using XSS. NOTE: Some of these
>   strings might be used for plugins or themes and hence this might break
>   some functionality. You are therefore strongly advised to take a
>   backup of your active .htaccess file before applying this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Check the ownership of the folders where these images are uploaded to.